# sticky scroll bar to the right

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

Hello i have a probleme with the vertical scroll bar as the gif is showing 
it dont stick to the right when i scroll cuz i did the width with fit-content

[image]

this is the code

```
.divdeux {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

can you help me please ?

Comment: You have an element with a vertical overflow inside an element with horizontal overflow. That's why the vertical scrollbar is outside of view. To fix that, you need a single element that overflows in both directions. We would, at the very least, need to see your HTML for that. Best create a [mcve] otherwise this question is going to be downvoted/closed pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

set width as 100%

```
.divdeux {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```